# boost interprocess : shared memory and stl types

Tags: c++, stl, boost, boost-interprocess

I have a simple struct :

```
struct MyType
{
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
}
```

and I'm putting it in a shared memory :

```
managed_shared_memory sharedMemory(open_or_create, "name", 65535);
MyType* pType = sharedMemory.construct<MyType>("myType")();
// ... setting pType members ...
```

If the two applications communicating with the shared memory are built using different version of Visual Studio (different version of stl implementation) should I put native types in the shared memory (e.g. char*) instead of stl types?

**Edit** :

I tried with

```
typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char> shared_string;
```

and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost.Interprocess often offers replacements for STL types, for usage in shared memory.  std::string, especially when just a member of a struct, will not be accessible from another process.  Other people also had [such a problem](http://groups.google.com/group/boost-list/browse_thread/thread/d8cfb127774d2b8e).

Comment: Yeah, see this section of the documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char> shared_string;
struct MyType
{
    shared_string name;
    shared_string description;
}
```